# Magento product insert method

Tags: php, magento, product

Thanks in advance for helping solve my issue.
in product save in magento this code not save the products. please find the solution of this problem:

```
<?php 
define('MAGENTO_MAGE_LOCATION','/home/admin/domains/public_html/importcsv1/app/Mage.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once MAGENTO_MAGE_LOCATION;
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http:www.examole.com/importcsv1/index.php/api/xmlrpc/');
$session = $client->call('login', array('aazi', 'asdfjsdf'));

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 

$product->setSku("12");
$product->setName("test name of the product");
$product->setWebsiteIDs(array('1'));
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setPrice("111");
$product->setInprice("222");
$product->setDescription("test description of the product");
$product->setShort_description("test short description of the product");
$product->setQty("11");
$product->setWeight("1.1"); 
$product->setCategoryIds(array(4));

try {
    $product->save();
    echo "<br>yes save new product insert into magento";
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    var_dump("NO new insert product save");
}
```

Can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to update an existing product, or to create a new one?

Comment: also, what errors do you get in your error log when all error logging is turned on? (or at least $e->getMessage())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should this line have a properly formatted URL? You seem to be missing characters between the colon and the www.

```
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http:www.examole.com/importcsv1/index.php/api/xmlrpc/');
```

I also think that `$product->setWebsiteIDs(array('1'));` should have a lowercase "D". Since the website ID is a required field, a misspelling here might cause problems.

HTH,
JD

Answer (score 1):

why are you using the API if you can do it much faster with a script and use `$product->save` like you did but don't mix it together!

replace

```
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http:www.examole.com/importcsv1/index.php/api/xmlrpc/');
$session = $client->call('login', array('aazi', 'asdfjsdf'));

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

--
with

```
Mage::init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use the backend of Magento? No need to use code...

Comment: Looking at his code, it seems like he wants to bind to an XmlRpc service to import products...